# Java code gives negative output

Tags: java, class, methods, output

I have a problem with the output of this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Parking
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the name of the parking lot:");
    String Name=scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the address of the parking lot:");
    String Address=scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of spots available for this parking lot:");
    int Num_Spots=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println();


    Parking myParking= new Parking(Name,Address,Num_Spots);

    System.out.println("This is the information you provided about this parking lot:\n"+ myParking);
    System.out.println();

    String toQuit;
    boolean quit=false;
    while(!quit)
    { 
    System.out.println("How many cars are exiting?");
    int CarsExiting=scan.nextInt();


    System.out.println("How many cars are entering?");
    int CarsEntering=scan.nextInt();
    while(CarsEntering>(Num_Spots+CarsExiting))
    {
        System.out.println("I'm sorry, the number of cars entering must be less than number of spots available.");
        System.out.println("Please inform the remaining customers that this lot is full.");
        System.out.println("How many cars are entering now?");
        CarsEntering=scan.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("The number of spots available now is: "+CarFlow(CarsEntering,CarsExiting));

        System.out.println("Press 'Q' to quit and any key to continue");
        toQuit=scan.next();
        if(toQuit.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
        {
            quit=true;
        }


    }


}//end main

private String _Name;
private String _Address;
private static int _Num_Spots;

// constructor for the parking class
public Parking(String Name,String Address, int Num_Spots) 
{
   _Name = Name;
   _Address = Address;
   _Num_Spots = Num_Spots;
}
//getters
public String getName() {return _Name;}
public String getAddress() {return _Address;}
public int getNumSpots() {return _Num_Spots;}

//setters
public void setName(String Name) {_Name=Name;}
public void setAddress(String Address) {_Address=Address;}
public void setNumSpots(int Num_Spots) {_Num_Spots=Num_Spots;}


//CarsFlow method()
public static int CarFlow(int CarEn,int CarEx)
{
    _Num_Spots=_Num_Spots+CarEx;
    _Num_Spots= _Num_Spots-CarEn;
    System.out.println("The number of cars exiting is "+CarEx);
    System.out.println("The number of cars entering is "+CarEn);

    return _Num_Spots;
}

public String toString()
{
    String Output="The name of the parking lot is: "+_Name+
                  "\nThe address of the parking lot is: "+_Address+    
                  "\nThe number of spots available in this parking lot   is: "+_Num_Spots;
    return Output;
}

}//end Parking class
```

The output works fine at first and then at some point when I enter a number of cars entering greater than the number of spots available, I get this output:

The number of cars exiting is 0
The number of cars entering is 10
The number of spots available now is: 0
Press 'Q' to quit and any key to continue
r
How many cars are exiting?
0
How many cars are entering?
3
The number of cars exiting is 0
The number of cars entering is 3
The number of spots available now is: -3

I am getting a negative number when the program is supposed to go through the while loop and print a message saying that the number of cars entering is greater than the number of spots available because 3 is greater than 0.

Comment: Your question is?

Comment: then write a @Test with the inut, and bug your code. You will then 1. find the bug 2. fix it and 3. have a test to make sure it do not appear again!

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using both the `Num_Spots` and `_Num_Spots` variables. You never assign the value of `Num_Spots` to `_Num_Spots`, so you're comparing the wrong integers.

Other than that, you may want to learn the Java coding standards. Variable and method (function) names never start with a capital, and they never have an underscore in them. You can see that in your code, that the highlighting gets confused because you're using your own coding standards.

Comment: I am working on learning more about Java coding standards. Can you explain me more about how to modify the _Num_Spots variable using Num_Spots. Thank you.

Comment: There are quite a few issues with your code. This is understandable, because it's all new to you. But what you should do is decide whether you want to do everything in the static `main` method, or in an instance of the `Parking` class. Now you're doing both, and that's causing issues. You instantiate the `Parking` instance with the `Num_Spots` variable, but then you keep comparing, in the `main` method, to that variable, whereas the `_Num_Spots` variable gets a different value every time you invoke `CarFlow`. The easiest fix is to compare against `_Num_Flow` instead of `Num_Flow`.

Comment: Having said that, the reason why it would work is because `_Num_Flow` is static, and that's actually a pretty big design problem. Hence my advice to do it either in `main`, or do everything in a non-static method of an instance of `Parking`.

Answer (score 0):

I see problem in this statement

```
while (CarsEntering > (Num_Spots + CarsExiting))
```

You are not updating Num_Spots variable after each iteration. You could modify as follows

```
System.out.println("The number of cars exiting is " + CarsExiting); //Take out this statements from CarFlow method
System.out.println("The number of cars entering is " + CarsEntering);//Take out this statements from CarFlow method
Num_Spots = CarFlow(CarsEntering, CarsExiting); //add this line above this statement System.out.println("The number of spots available now is: 
System.out.println("The number of spots available now is: " + Num_Spots);
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: This is not working. It is giving me more weird outputs.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure if you modified the code this way https://ideone.com/DjTHfl

Comment: Yes I did. This is an output example I got:
This is the information you provided about this parking lot:
The name of the parking lot is: hh
The address of the parking lot is: hh
The number of spots available in this parking lot is: 10

How many cars are exiting?
2
How many cars are entering?
12
The number of cars exiting is 2
The number of cars entering is 12
The number of spots available now is: -10
Press 'Q' to quit and any key to continue

Comment: @Jallous55 Check out the output I have got in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You want to separate the class that makes your calculation from the main application that controls the user input/output.

Then you can easily start to drive the behavior of you application with unit tests. And that will make it easy for you to track down bugs and change your implementation.

It is easy to see that carFlow() can return negative result. This could be a first test. I also think that the check in your while-statement is wrong, why do you want to add exiting cards to Num_spots?

this could be a first test to carFlow() and I do think you want to add more responsibility to this method in your application. This test fails since -1 is not 0!

```
@Test
public void testNumberOfCardEnteringBiggerThanNumberOfSpots() {
    Parking underTest = new Parking("Unit Test", "Some street", 0);
    int actual = underTest.CarFlow(1, 0);

    Assert.assertEquals(0, actual);
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I think this is too advanced stuff for me. I am still a beginner.